# Saving an object as JSON, and then loading it later?

Tags: php

I know how to JSON encode and decode an object. That's no biggie. However, I've reached a situation where I need to save `$this` as a JSON string, and then later, populate `$this`'s attributes from that JSON string.

In other words, I don't want to get a new instance of an object with the data from the JSON string, I want to apply it to an existing object.

How can I do that?

Comment: If an attribute is currently defined on `$this` but not defined on your encoded object, what do you want to happen with that attribute when you apply the encoded data to `$this`?

Comment: Nothing. Leave the attribute of `$this` to its old value. My object always has its attributes fully populated.

Comment: You can just use encode inside your class so you have the json inside your object as an object. Like `$instance->jsonecodestuf->etc`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the defined attributes of an object using `get_object_vars()` http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-object-vars.php

```
class MyClass
{
    function populateFromJSON($data)
    {
        $o = json_decode($data);
        $attributes = get_object_vars($o);
        if (is_array($attributes)) {
            foreach ($attributes as $name => $val) {
                $this->$name = $val;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not just use `json_decode($data, true)` which returns arrays instead of objects.

Comment: That leads to another issue with this answer.  How does it handle attributes which are themselves objects?  Not very well.

Comment: Very true; especially if they're instances of other objects, rather than just stdClass.  There's no quick and dirty solution that solves all.